# Are there any patterns for API's which need to return full or partial object graphs?

Tags: c#, api, design-patterns

Are there any patterns/solutions to solve the problem of having an API call which in one scenario may need to return a full object graph (say a `manager` object and all it's staff relations) and in another may just return a single `manager` object?

The ideas we're currently passing around are:

1. Many methods
   In the example above you'd have one method called `get_manager()` and another called `get_manager_deep()`.
2. Many objects
   Similar to 1. you have two methods, one returns a `manager` and one returns a `manager_with_staff`
3. Data-driven API
   Here the method accepts some kind of query (maybe XML) which defines exactly what kind of object you want back, and the method returns perhaps a dynamic object matching the query.

NB. These examples are very simplified, in reality the methods may need to specify where parts of the data comes from - ActiveDirectory/DB.

Anyone ever come across problems like this?

**EDIT** - Main driving force of the design is to have a clean and simple (but effective) API and object model. So some of the above examples result in potentially large (and possibly confusing) object graphs. Having too many (hopefully unnecessary) methods/classes can be a maintenance problem.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  Query efficiency?

Comment: i think you should try creating one according to your needs.. you just need two concepts.. 1. Chaining, 2. Recursion..

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh Chaining was the solution we used in the end. Feel free to post that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @AdamNaylor just posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try creating one according to your needs.. you just need two concepts.. 
1. Method Chaining 
2. Recursion

A really good article of what Method Chaining is at Wikipedia 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

In a project I worked on that didn't use any real ORM we solved the problem something like this:

```
class Manager { 
  public List<Employee> Staff { get;set;} // Not populated by default.
}

interface IEmployeeDataAccess {
  List<Staff> GetStaffForManagers(int[] managerIds);
}
```

Then created builder classes that could populate the object graph:

```
new ManagerBuilder().From(managers).WithEmployees(employeeDataAccess).Build();
```

The builders could be chained together:

```
new ManagerBuilder()
  .From(managers)
  .WithEmployees(employeeDataAccess, employeeBuilder => 
    employeeBuilder.WithLeaveRequests())
  .Build();
```

Allowing us to fetch the desired amout of data with as few trips to the database as possible.